# Export firebase

Tags: firebase, rest-firebase

I was wondering if it is possible to export firebase data (perhaps as a JSON object) in frequent "cycles". The main reason I'm asking this is because I would like to capture the data at specific points of time in order to perform a range of analytics upon them / identify specific patterns. I'm interested in any operations / methods that are part of the Firebase API - maybe some kind of web hook, or other workarounds that would enable me to do this!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I could not find anything on the web / docs (maybe I've over read it?).

Comment: Response below. If you can provide more information about your use case I can provide a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firebase has a full-featured REST API, so the simplest thing to do is just poll the REST API on a regular basis. REST API docs are here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api-quickstart.html

You can also get full access to your Firebase data using the Node.js client. This allows you to attach callbacks to your data and act on changes immediately when they occur from your own server: https://www.firebase.com/docs/nodejs-quickstart.html

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the quick reply. I had thought of those solutions but was wondering if I was missing something, maybe some firebase export webhook or another option that would make the process cleaner! Anyway I didn't find anything else so I guess the solution is as you described it! Cheers!

Comment: I'm curious about the same thing as Alex, but from a back-ups perspective. Is there a way to get access to the backups Firebase itself creates on a normal basis? (Heroku does this as part of their Postgres offering, which I've found quite nice.)

Comment: how we can do with jquery and from where we get access_token

Answer (score 8):

Firebase now provides private backup option. For more information checkout  [private backup for Firebase data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can  export firebase data in Json object, just make a curl request like below:

```
curl 'https://MyBase.firebaseio.com/MyPoint.json?auth=MyAuth&print=pretty'
```

in linux terminal and you get all your child structure

Comment: Your answer adds no value to the answer given almost 5 years ago: **poll the REST API on a regular basis**

Comment: How do you do this if the data is too large?