# Is it possible to backup Firebase DB?

Tags: firebase

Was wondering if there are any common practices in backup up a firebase DB.  My concern is some process accidentally wiping out our Database.

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "firebase DB backup" shows a number of Github projects to do this.

Comment: You can get all the data out of your Firebase easily by curling `https://<your>.firebaseio.com/.json`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079436/export-firebase?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549299/how-to-migrate-data-settings-from-one-firebase-to-another/15551711#15551711

Answer (score 45):

As of the time of this question, Firebase backs up all instances daily. So while keeping your own backups may still be useful, it's not essential.

To create your own backups, you can simply curl the data:

```
curl https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/.json?format=export
```

Note that for multiple gigabytes of data, this will slow things down and lock read access for a short period. It would be better in this case to chunk the backups and work with smaller portions. The [shallow parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-query-parameters) can help here by providing a list of keys for any given path in Firebase, without having to fetch the data first.

```
curl https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/.json?shallow=true
```

As previously mentioned, there are also several GitHub libs available for this, and incremental backups are practical with some creativity and a worker thread on the real-time SDK.

Comment: Clarification: It seems the auto backup is only there for the "Bonfire" plan and above currently https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html

Comment: Incorrect. You're referring to private backups which are pushed out to a GCS or S3 bucket. Firebase backs up all instances daily for all plans, including free, as noted in my answer.

Comment: Are you saying you back them up ***internally***?  Because that's not the same.  Having to contact support to restore a backup is something you should clarify in your post.... unless I am missing some functionality, in that case, please point to it.  Your answer as written is misleading.

Comment: Your downvote is noted. Have a great day.

Comment: Only downvoted because you aren't giving the complete answer, I would happily change it if you didnt evade the question with snarky little comments.  I came to this question looking for the answer and am still wondering what the difference is between private backups and what you describe.  Why cant you just say?  Are you really the dev evangelist at firebase?   (You are behaving awfully unprofessionally).

Comment: There is nothing misleading or dishonest about the answer here. It explains how to create one's own backups, which was the question. It notes that Firebase provides backups of data. As of the time of writing the answer, private backups did not exist. Your opinion is noted and I've considered it. I appreciate the feedback. Feel free to post your own answer if you're unhappy with this one. No hard feelings. No attitudes required.

Comment: Fair enough, if you clarified how one would go about restoring a daily backup, I personally think that could improve the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @kato for this answer. I've used this with nodejs to perform daily backup. https://github.com/hardiksondagar/firebase-backup.
Again thanks :-)

Comment: Is this still the case as of today (after the migration to the Google Cloud)?  So if someone fat fingered and deleted my entire DB tonight, I could e-mail Firebase support and have it restored to last night's state?  How many days does this internal Firebase back-up go back for?

Comment: It's still the same database and we're still Firebase. Integrating with GCP and adding more features didn't involve removing common sense. We still have disaster recovery backups, as well as [Private Backups](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/03/private-backups-for-firebase-data_21.html), and we still make them available to you as necessary.

Comment: How do you log in with CURL?

Comment: @Kato: Is the answer still valid as of today, in June, 2017? Because from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/backups) link it seems 'automated daily backups' are available only for the 'Blaze' plan, not the free plan.

Comment: @Kato while backing up data from firebase, it return
{
      "error" : "Internal server error."
}

request: curl https://{URL}?format=export -o backup.db

Comment: See my answer above. Firebase Firestore now support it natively.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to authenticate this way, so this solution doesn't work unless the whole database is accessible to read by all, which might not be advisable in many cases...

Comment: Auth via REST API is covered in the doc and possible.

Answer (score 15):

There are now "Import Data" and "Export Data" buttons on the data page of the web interface for every project, so you can now backup your data with a button click!

[image: Import and Export buttons]

Comment: Hmm, not seeing these in the database tab. Where is that screenshot taken?

Comment: Looks like now you need to click on the three vertical dots up in the right hand corner to see export and import.

Comment: Ah, just found the three dots in the Realtime DB. Looks like there's no option to import/export for Firestore.

Comment: @Patrick Firebase's official documentation recommends their backup service through GCP for Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import. You can automate the CLI commands with a scheduled CRON job. The back-up files are not JSON, but instead some manipulation of LevelDB output.

Comment: @SeanPerkins yeah, saw that. But ugh all that just to export json? Really, Google? I'd take a one-button solution over that any day.

Answer (score 9):

just yesterday wrote a shell-script, which utilizes firebase-tools (`npm install -g firebase-tools`), in order to have these database dumps contained within my regular backup `cronjob`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 is the Firebase projectId.
# $2 is the destination directory. 
# example usage: cron_firebase.sh project-12345 /home/backups/firebase
# currently being triggered by /etc/cron.hourly/firebase-hourly.cron
PROJECTID=$1
DESTINATION=$2
FIREBASE="$(which firebase)"
NOW="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")"
cd $DESTINATION
$FIREBASE --project $PROJECTID database:get / > ./$PROJECTID.$NOW.json
tar -pczf $PROJECTID.$NOW.tar.gz ./$PROJECTID.$NOW.json && rm ./$PROJECTID.$NOW.json
```

**update**: in the meanwhile, one can *auto backup* to Google Cloud Storage Bucket

...goto `Firebase Console` -> `Realtime Database` -> and click tab [Backups](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/backups).

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to backup and restore **Firebase Firestore** using Cloud Firestore managed export and import service

You do it by:

1. [Create a Cloud Storage bucket for your project](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets):
2. Set up **gcloud** for your project using `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`

**EXPORT**

**Export all** by calling
`gcloud alpha firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`
Or **Export a specific collection** using
`gcloud alpha firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID_1]','[COLLECTION_ID_2]'`

**IMPORT**

**Import all** by calling
`gcloud alpha firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/`
where [BUCKET_NAME] and [EXPORT_PREFIX] point to the location of your export files. For example - `gcloud alpha firestore import gs://exports-bucket/2017-05-25T23:54:39_76544/`

**Import a specific collection** by calling:
`gcloud alpha firestore import --collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID_1]','[COLLECTION_ID_2]' gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/`

Full instructions are available here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: Could you expand on this answer by including some of the key features mentioned on that page *in the answer itself*? As it stands, if the URL changes or goes down this answer would effectively become useless.

Comment: Thank you. @MichaelDodd I've added more info. See if that is more useful now.

Comment: Can you show how to schedule this using Firebase Cron? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

Comment: @aaronvargas See this blog post to get your answer https://blog.emad.in/automate-firestore-db-backups/ :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand @kato's answer using curl.

I was looking for ways to run the command every night. My solution:
1) created a compute engine (basically a VM) in Google Cloud. You might be familiar with EC2 if you are from AWS world.
2) Wrote a simple cronjob, something like this

> `` 0 23 * * * /usr/bin/curl https://yourdatabaseurl.com/.json?format=export -o /tmp/backuptest_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.bk ``

I am sure there might be a simpler way to do this within the **free** tier itself.
Like using cloud functions.

Comment: just added the link for automated backups, which might be that "simpler way".