# How to backup a full project of firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am faced a problem. I have a project which is in firebase. I have used there firebase Authenticate, Firebase realtime database, Firebase function and some more. Now I have changed my decision. I want to make my own server where I will set up and manage everything.
So that I want to backup my project to move all data to other framework like spring boot project.

In this situation how can I get the whole project? User Auth data, Firebase Realtime database, Firestore etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write code or use the CLI to query all of the data you want, and write it to a place you want.  Firebase does not provide a tool to do all this automatically for an entire project. You will need to deal with each product's data separately.

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) or the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) to access data from the products you listed.

See also:

- [Is it possible to backup Firebase DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910784/is-it-possible-to-backup-firebase-db)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Comment: This is a big problem for the user. I think google clouds need to fix it

Comment: You're certainly welcome to send your feedback to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  Stack Overflow can't help you with this any more than what you see here, given that this is a community-supported site not run by Google.